# signin and signup bootstrap modals with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two bootstrap modals one for sign in and another one for signup. Inside each of them, there is a form that handles the action (I'm not doing stuff in a separate page).
A connection page is included in this project to handle the connection success and failure.
First, they were working but after adding the session they don't perform anything and just redirect me to the same page I will put the code below if anyone can tell me what causes the problem or were is the problem in my code I would be glad .. regards

```
session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']))
    {
        header('Location:home.php');
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if(isset($_POST['signin']))
        {
            // Get Variables From The Form By Their Name Attributes
            $username = $_POST['emailOrMobile'];
            $password = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            // Check if the user exist in database
            $stmt = $con->prepare("select ID,firstName,email,mobile,password,status from users where (email=? or mobile =?) and password=?");
            $stmt->execute(array($username,$username,$password));
            $info=$stmt->fetch();
            $count=$stmt->rowCount();

            if($count>0)
            {
                if(!$info["status"]==0)
                {
                    $_SESSION['ID'] = $info["ID"];
                    $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $info["firstName"];
                    header('Location:home.php');
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['ID'] = $info["ID"];
                    $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $info["firstName"];
                    $_SESSION['mobile'] = $info["mobile"];
                    header('Location:register.php');
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                header('Location:errors.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['signup']))
        {
            // Get Variables From The Form By Their Name Attributes
            $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
            $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
            $password = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $birthDate = $_POST['birthDate'];
            if(!empty($_POST['gender']))
            {
                $gender = $_POST['gender'];
            }
            else
            {
                $gender = 0;
            }

            // Generating serial token for account verification
            $tokens = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
            $serial = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
            {
                for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) 
                {
                    $serial .= $tokens[rand(0, 35)];
                }
                if ($i < 3) {
                    $serial .= '-';
                }
            }

            // Validate The Form
            $formErrors=array(); // Empty Array Defined For Containing Error Messages Of Empty Inputs
            if(strlen($firstName) < 3)
            {
                $formErrors[]='first Name can not be less than <strong>3 characters</strong>';  
            }
            if(strlen($firstName) > 255)
            {
                $formErrors[]='first Name can not be greater than <strong>255 characters</strong>'; 
            }
            if(empty($firstName))
            {
                $formErrors[]='First Name can not be <strong>empty</strong>';   
            }
            if(strlen($lastName) < 3)
            {
                $formErrors[]='Last Name can not be less than <strong>3 characters</strong>';   
            }
            if(strlen($lastName) > 255)
            {
                $formErrors[]='Last Name can not be greater than <strong>255 characters</strong>';  
            }
            if(empty($lastName))
            {
                $formErrors[]='Last Name can not be <strong>empty</strong>';    
            }
            if(strlen($mobile) > 12)
            {
                $formErrors[]='Mobile number can not be greater than <strong>12 characters</strong>';
            }
            if(empty($mobile))
            {
                $formErrors[]='Mobile can not be <strong>empty</strong>';   
            }
            if(empty($email))
            {
                $formErrors[]='Email can not be <strong>empty</strong>';    
            }
            if(empty($birthDate))
            {
                $formErrors[]='Birth Date can not be <strong>empty</strong>';   
            }

            // If There Is No Error Procced The Insert Operation
            if(empty($formErrors))
            {
                // Insert User Info In Database
                $stmt = $con->prepare("insert into users (ID , firstName , lastName , email , mobile , password , birthDate , gender , status , token) values (DEFAULT , :ufirstName , :ulastName , :uemail , :umobile , :upassword , :ubirthDate , :ugender , 0 , :utoken)");
                $stmt-> execute(array(
                    'ufirstName' => $firstName,
                    'ulastName' => $lastName,
                    'uemail' => $email,
                    'umobile' => $mobile,
                    'upassword' => $password,
                    'ubirthDate' => $birthDate,
                    'ugender' => $gender,
                    'utoken' => $serial
                )); // Here The Execution Of The Query Ends After Inserting The Variables Inside The Values Defined Teporerly In Query
                //$_SESSION['ID'] = $info["ID"];
                $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $firstName;
                $_SESSION['mobile'] = $mobile;
                header('Location:register.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the modals code:

```
<!-- Signin Popup model -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="text-center">LOGIN</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="emailOrMobile" required="" autocomplete="off" />
                        <label>Email or Mobile</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" required="" autocomplete="off" />
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn btn btn-block" name="signin">Signin</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p>Dont have an account?</p>
                <button id="join-trigger" class="signup-trigger-btn btn">Signup</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Signup Popup model -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="text-center">Signup</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" required="" autocomplete="off">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" required="" autocomplete="off">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="email" name="email" required="" autocomplete="off">
                        <label>Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="tel" name="mobile" required="" autocomplete="off">
                        <label>Mobile</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" required="" autocomplete="off">
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="birthDate" required="" id="datetimepicker">
                        <label>Birth Date</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="gender-div">
                            <label>Gender</label>
                            <label class="gender">Male</label>
                            <label class="gender">Female</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="1" />       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn btn btn-block" name="signup">SIGN UP</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p>Already have an account?</p>
                <button id="login-trigger" class="signin-trigger-btn btn">Signin</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't `SELECT` against the password when it's been hashed with `password_hash()`. You have to grab the record for the user, then pass the existing hashed password and the provided unhashed password to the `password_verify()` function.

Comment: OK I'll handle this thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexHowansky now I'm comparing status field value which is a boolean data type field in my table . If it is true then the user should be redirected to home page else he must be directed to register page what's wrong with my code here  if(!$info["status"]==0)